# How do I add a listener to a search form in Angular material?

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-material

I'm working with Angular material and I have a search form. As shown in the following code, I have a button and after a click event on the button, the words written in the search form are given to the  `searchProductByName` method as parameters. I'd like to substitute the button with a listener that, after having written something in the form and having clicked on enter (instead of the button), grabs the things written in the search form and passes them to the `searchProductByName` method as parameters. Is there a way to do so?

```
<form class="search-form" >
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
      <mat-label >Search</mat-label>
      <input #input type="text" ngModel name="name" class="form-control" id="name"
             aria-label="Search"
             matInput
             >
             <button (click)="searchProductByName(input.value)" routerLink="/products/searchProduct/by_name"  routerLinkActive="active">Go</button>

    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `searchPruductByName` is a method that is using http request to search from backend, for example - I would suggest to also implement debounce'ing the search as well. Otherwise it would search with each keystroke. A nice elegant way would be to use a debounce decorator. https://medium.com/time-machine/how-to-implement-debounce-decorator-2e963b70cd27

```html
<form class="search-form" >
    <input #input type="text" ngModel name="name" class="form-control" id="name"
         (input)="searchProductByName($event); onInput($event)" 
         aria-label="Search"
         matInput>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

```js
onInput(event: any) {     
   console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

To navigate to link on pressing "Enter" add to constructor Router and then use router to navigate.

```js
constructor(router: Router) {}

onNavigate() {
// other stuff
this.router.navigateByUrl('/products/searchProduct/by_name')
}
```

```html
<input (keyup.enter)="searchProductByName(input.value); onNavigate()">
```

Comment: Thanks! After clicking enter I'd like to be redirected to the link specified in the button too, do you know how to add this functionality?

Comment: To navigate to link on pressing "Enter" add to constructor Router and then use router to navigate. `this.router.navigateByUrl('/products/searchProduct/by_name')`

Comment: The navigation to the link works correcty in this way, but `searchProductByName(input.value)` doesn't work, it seems as if `input.value` is empty. If I give a certain input to the form and click the button, several results are displayed, while if I give the same input to the form and I press enter there isn't any result.

Comment: With this approach the console prints out this error: `ERROR Error: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource`

Comment: html:`<input (input)="onInput($event)">`

ts `onInput(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do that in template is add `keyup` event to the input:

```
<form class="search-form" >
    <input #input type="text" ngModel name="name" class="form-control" id="name"
         (keyup.enter)="searchProductByName(input.value)" 
         aria-label="Search"
         matInput
         >
    <button (click)="searchProductByName(input.value)" routerLink="/products/searchProduct/by_name"  routerLinkActive="active">Go</button>

  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Or you can get your input element in component with `ViewChild` and make listener there.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to be redirected to the following link `routerLink="/products/searchProduct/by_name"` after clicking enter too, should I write the following?  `<input #input type="text" ngModel name="name" class="form-control" id="name" (keyup.enter)="searchProductByName(input.value)" routerLink="/products/searchProduct/by_name"  routerLinkActive="active" aria-label="Search" matInput>`

Comment: Nope, but you can make function that invokes searchProductByName and navigate. Like this:
`...(keyup.enter)="searchAndRedirect(input.value)" ...`
- inside component:
`searchAndRedirect(value: string) { 
  this.searchProductByName(value);
  this.redirectTo(...);
}`
Or something like this. Maybe you need observable to catch the result before redirect?

Comment: `redirectTo` should be a method that redirects to `/products/searchProduct/by_name`?

Comment: yes, it should.